Fast, coordinate-free 8-way neighbors in Haskell
I would like to compute the 8-way neighbors of every element in a rectangular list of lists xss :: [[a]], preserving the original element and defaulting on the boundary. In particular, I want to write a function neighbors :: a -> [[a]] -> [[NonEmpty a]] where each inner list has length 9, with the head being the original element.
Here is the output I'm expecting:
ghci> mapM_ print [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
ghci> mapM_ (mapM_ print) $ neighbors 0 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[1,0,0,0,0,2,0,4,5]
[2,0,0,0,1,3,4,5,6]
[3,0,0,0,2,0,5,6,0]
[4,0,1,2,0,5,0,7,8]
[5,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9]
[6,2,3,0,5,0,8,9,0]
[7,0,4,5,0,8,0,0,0]
[8,4,5,6,7,9,0,0,0]
[9,5,6,0,8,0,0,0,0]

I have read the nice answers to this old question, but it doesn't quite satisfy these requirements because it generates pairs and destroys the structure of the original matrix.
However I am hoping it is possible to write something similarly concise.
I've come up with two very bad partial solutions, one which performs a ton of rotations and another which is not coordinate-free:
-- | Add a ring of default elements around a 2d array.
augment :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
augment d m = map (pad d) . pad (replicate ncols d) $ m
  where
    pad d' = reverse . (d' :) . reverse . (d' :)
    ncols = foldr (max . length) 0 m

-- | Neighbors in a 2d array, with default.
neighbors1 :: a -> [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
neighbors1 d m = map transpose $ transpose $ map ($ augment d m) [middle, upL, up, upR, left, right, downL, down, downR]
  where
    rot   = transpose . reverse
    right = map (drop 2) . both (drop 1)
    up    = rot . rot . rot . right . rot
    left  = rot . rot . right . rot . rot
    down  = rot . right . rot . rot . rot
    downR = map (drop 2) . drop 2
    upR   = rot . rot . rot . downR . rot
    upL   = rot . rot . downR . rot . rot
    downL = rot . downR . rot . rot . rot
    middle = map (both (drop 1)) . both (drop 1)
    both f = reverse . f . reverse . f

-- | Includes center element as head.
-- O(mn*log(mn))  Data.Map.Strict
-- O(mn)          Data.HashMap.Strict
neighbors :: a -> [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
neighbors d zss = unmaybe [[map (vals !?) (nbs x y) | y <- [0..n-1]] | x <- [0..m-1]]
  where
    unmaybe = (map . map . map) (fromMaybe d)
    (m, n) = (length zss, maybe 0 length $ listToMaybe zss)
    nbs x y = (x,y) : [(i,j) | i <- [x-1..x+1], j <- [y-1..y+1], (i,j) /= (x,y)]
    vals = M.fromAscList [((i,j),z) | (i,zs) <- zip [0..] zss, (j,z) <- zip [0..] zs]

Also note that the augment function is a bit gross. Perhaps it can be done more elegantly with zipWith const? But I can't figure out how. I also tried using Maybes instead of defaults, which would also be acceptable, but once I have an array of the form [Maybe [Maybe a]], I can't figure out how to operate on it.
Edit: I've come up with a slightly better version that I will include for posterity, but I think the answers so far are probably still superior. I still couldn't figure out the NonEmpty bit.
This still makes use of this ugly augment function. I wrote another version of it but they both seem inelegant.
rev :: ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]
rev f  = reverse . f . reverse

both :: ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]
both f = rev f . f

-- | Add a ring of default elements around a 2d array.
augment :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
augment d xss = map (pad d) . pad (replicate n d) $ xss
  where
    pad d' = both (d':)
    n = maybe 0 length (listToMaybe xss)

-- | Add a ring of default elements around a 2d array.
augment' :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
augment' _ []         = []
augment' d xss@(xs:_) = map (pad d) . pad ds $ xss
  where
    pad d' = both (d':)
    ds = map (const d) xs

-- | Neighbors in a 2d array, with default.
neighbors1 :: a -> [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
neighbors1 d m = map transpose $ transpose $ map ($ augment d m)
  --  vertical horizontal
  [   center . map center
  ,   center . map down
  ,   center . map up
  ,   down   . map center
  ,   up     . map center
  ,   down   . map down
  ,   down   . map up
  ,   up     . map down
  ,   up     . map up
  ]
  where
    center = both (drop 1)
    down   = drop 2
    up     = rev down


I don't really understand the output of neighbors 0, 0 is the element for which you want to find the neighbors? What are the different rows?

The reason the coordinate function works slow, is only because you each time create an array. Whereas typically you make it once, and then reuse it through multiple calls.

The first row in the output is the list of neighbors of 1. The 0 is the default element, which pads out each list of neighbors such that they are homogeneous.

See the (fromMaybe d) in the definition of neighbors.

Author of the top answer at the linked question here. Are you sure this isn't a dupe? To me, it looks like the same technique -- with just a few structural changes, e.g. a map snd at the end and not concating in one or two strategic locations -- ought to work fine.

@DanielWagner You're probably right! I wasn't able to see that at the time of writing. But I suppose it feels a bit wasteful to do everything in terms of tuples just to throw them away at the end, no? I'd hope that we'd end up with something cleaner and shorter if we don't need the associations. But perhaps then there's no analogue of your map swap operation.

Do you know if it's possible to write the non-concatenating version of downRight :: [[a]] -> [[(a,a)]] as down . right or right . down for appropriate (nontrivial) choices of down and right?

@lanf What are you trying to achieve here, i.e. why do you need the neighbors? Comonads might come in handy.

@Franky Can you elaborate a bit on that? I've really never used them but I'm open to an alternative approach! Well for matrix problems that involve "pervasive" operations. The rotting oranges problem is a good example.

Here is an adapted version of Li-yao Xia's solution. I really like the idea of arranging the transforms in the list in the shape of a 3x3 grid, but I wanted to make it easier to textually transform this back and forth from 4-way neighbors to 8-way neighbors, and from the NonEmpty version to the one that excludes the middle.
-- Rotate the outermost axis to the innermost position.
transpose3D :: [[[a]]] -> [[[a]]]
transpose3D = map transpose . transpose

zipWith2D :: (a -> b -> c) -> [[a]] -> [[b]] -> [[c]]
zipWith2D = zipWith . zipWith

neighbors6 :: a -> [[a]] -> [[NonEmpty a]]
neighbors6 d m = zipWith2D (:|) m $ transpose3D $ map ($ m)
  [ up
  , down
  , left
  , right
  , up . left
  , up . right
  , down . left
  , down . right
  ]
  where
    up    = (repeat d :)
    down  = (++ [repeat d]) . drop 1
    left  = map (d :)
    right = map ((++ [d]) . drop 1)

In the above we can just delete the zipWith2D call and it becomes [[[a]]] with only neighbors, no center element, and we can also just delete the last four lines of the list and get cardinals.
It's worth noting that his answer is faster than anything else I've tried in a very rudimentary benchmark using deepseq.

You can collect neighbors by zipping the matrix with shifted copies of itself.
To see more clearly, here is the type of matrices.
type Matrix a = [[a]]

Define zipping of two matrices
matrixZipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> Matrix a -> Matrix b -> Matrix c
matrixZipWith = zipWith . zipWith

The element at indices (i,j) of the output Matrix c is the combination of the elements at the same indices (i,j) of the two input Matrix a and Matrix b.
We can iterate matrixZipWith to obtain zipping of N matrices. As it turns out, zipping is a generalization of transposition.
-- NonEmpty-Matrix transposition
transposeNEM :: NonEmpty (Matrix a) -> Matrix (NonEmpty a)
transposeNEM (x :| xs) = matrixZipWith (:|) x (transposeLM xs)

-- List-Matrix transposition
transposeLM :: [Matrix a] -> Matrix [a]
transposeLM (x : xs) = matrixZipWith (:) x (transposeLM xs)
transposeLM [] = repeat (repeat [])

In your definition you defined the 8 shifting operations as rotations of right and downR shifting. Instead, define up, down, left, right directly in terms of row/column insertion.
For example, down removes the first row and inserts a sentinel row at the end. Visually, this operation shifts the matrix "up", but the result in terms of reindexing is that each matrix cell is replaced with its "down" neighbor, which is the more intuitive point of view when you look at the matrix of neighbors in the definition of neighbors below.
down :: Matrix a -> Matrix a
down = (++ [repeat d]) . drop 1

Compose these to get the diagonal shifts. Put all of the shifts together in a list, apply them to the input matrix, and zip (= transpose) it all up.
neighbors :: a -> [[a]] -> [[NonEmpty a]]
neighbors d m = transposeNE2 (fmap ($ m) (id :|
    [ up   . left, up  , up   . right
    ,        left,              right
    , down . left, down, down . right]))
  where
    down = (++ [repeat d]) . drop 1
    up = (repeat d :)
    right = map ((++ [d]) . drop 1)
    left = map (d :)


Full code:
import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmpty(..))

type Matrix a = [[a]]

matrixZipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> Matrix a -> Matrix b -> Matrix c
matrixZipWith = zipWith . zipWith

transposeNEM :: NonEmpty (Matrix a) -> Matrix (NonEmpty a)
transposeNEM (x :| xs) = matrixZipWith (:|) x (transposeLM xs)

transposeLM :: [Matrix a] -> Matrix [a]
transposeLM (x : xs) = matrixZipWith (:) x (transposeLM xs)
transposeLM [] = repeat (repeat [])

neighbors :: a -> [[a]] -> [[NonEmpty a]]
neighbors d m = transposeNE2 (fmap ($ m) (id :|
    [ up   . left, up  , up   . right
    ,        left,              right
    , down . left, down, down . right]))
  where
    down = (++ [repeat d]) . drop 1
    up = (repeat d :)
    right = map ((++ [d]) . drop 1)
    left = map (d :)

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ (mapM_ print) $ neighbors 0 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]


With some "clever" bookkeeping, we can scan the lists and thus construct the neighbors iteratively, with:
import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmpty ((:|)))

scanRow' :: [a] -> [NonEmpty a]
scanRow' (x1 : x2 : xs) = go x1 x2 xs
  where
    go l x [] = []
    go l x (r : rs) = (x :| [l, r]) : go x r rs
scanRow' [] = []
so if we evaluate scanRow' [0,1,2,3,0], we get:
[1,0,2]
[2,1,3]
[3,2,0]

the only thing left to do is add the elements of the row above and below, we can do this by constructing a new version of scanRow that takes the three elements of the top row and bottom row, and advances one hop for both of these, like:
scanRow :: [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [NonEmpty a]
scanRow (x1 : x2 : xs) = go x1 x2 xs
  where
    go l x [] t b = []
    go l x (r : rs) t@(_ : ts) b@(_ : bs) = (x :| (take 3 t ++ l : r : take 3 b)) : go x r rs ts bs
scanRow _ = const (const [])
so this gives us for scanRow [0,4,5,6,0] [0,1,2,3,0] [0,7,8,9,0]:
[4,0,1,2,0,5,0,7,8]
[5,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9]
[6,2,3,0,5,0,8,9,0]

so we now need a function that passes the lists for each row to scanRow:
addDefault :: a -> [a] -> [a]
addDefault x xs = x : xs ++ [x]

neighbors :: a -> [[a]] -> [[NonEmpty a]]
neighbors d (r : rs) = go t0 (addDefault d r) (map (addDefault d) rs ++ [t0])
  where
    t0 = repeat d
    go t r (b : bs) = scanRow r t b : go r b bs
    go _ _ [] = []
For a 3×3 matrix, we thus get:
ghci> neighbors 0 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[
  [
    1 :| [0,0,0,0,2,0,4,5],
    2 :| [0,0,0,1,3,4,5,6],
    3 :| [0,0,0,2,0,5,6,0],
  ], [
    4 :| [0,1,2,0,5,0,7,8],
    5 :| [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9],
    6 :| [2,3,0,5,0,8,9,0],
  ], [
    7 :| [0,4,5,0,8,0,0,0],
    8 :| [4,5,6,7,9,0,0,0],
    9 :| [5,6,0,8,0,0,0,0]
  ]
]

This will thus move through the matrix, but does not have to calculate all the lists of neighbors, or at least not if not necessary. If we are for example only interested in the fifth element, and print that one, the other items will not get fully evaluated. It also does not require all the rows in memory at the same time: the approach needs three rows in memory, the rest can be garbage collected, or remain unevaluated.

A nice solution, and much faster than the proposed alternatives.  Note that it doesn't quite match the spec -- the OP wanted a return value of type [[NonEmpty a]] rather than [NonEmpty a] to preserve the row/column structure of the original matrix, so I think you need to replace ++ with : in the definition of go.

@K.A.Buhr: aarggh, yes. Thanks :)
